# How do I Powershell Pester Test for ThrowTerminatingError

Tags: powershell, testing, pester

How do I Powershell Pester Test for ThrowTerminatingError ?

```
catch
{
    $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError( $PSItem )
}
```

Output:

```
Missed command:

File                  Class Function          Line Command
----                  ----- --------          ---- -------
Test-ServerOnline.ps1       Test-ServerOnline   50 $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError( $PSItem )
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to **catch a *terminating* error (an exception)** in a Pester test:

- you must **enclose the input command in a *script block* (`{ ... }`)**
- and test for whether such an error did / did not occur with 
  **`Should -Throw` / `Should -Not -Throw`**

Note: If you **also want to handle *non-terminating* errors** this way, which `Should -Throw` does *not* handle:

- If the input command calls a cmdlet / advanced function, add common parameter `-ErrorAction Stop` to it, which promotes the (first) non-terminating error to a (script)-terminating (fatal) one.
- Otherwise, set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` as the first statement *inside the script block*.

---

**Examples**:

<sup>Note: For brevity, the following snippets aren't full Pester tests and call just the Pester `Should` cmdlet; however, you *can* call them as-is, which case a *successful test* is implied by receiving *no output*.  See the bottom section for a complete example.</sup>

```
# Note the { ... } around the command.
{ 1 / 0 } | Should -Throw
```

The above test passes, because `1 / 0` creates a statement-terminating error, which is the same error type that `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()` produces.

With a *non-terminating* error *promoted to a terminating one* with `-ErrorAction Stop`

```
# Note: Without -ErrorAction Stop, the test would fail, because
#       not finding a file is a non-terminating error.
{ Get-Item NoSuchFile -ErrorAction Stop } | Should -Throw
```

Additionally, you can **test for specific *error IDs***, using the **`-ErrorId`** parameter:

```
{ 1 / 0 } | Should -Throw -ErrorId RuntimeException
```

The above test passes, because the error record produced by the statement-terminating error triggered with `1 / 0` (as also recorded in the automatic `$Error` variable), has a `.FullyQualifiedErrorId` value of `RuntimeException` (verify with `$Error[0].FullyQualifiedErrorId` afterwards).

Note: **`-ErrorId` performs literal *substring matching***, so that `-ErrorId Runtime` would work too in the command above.

Alternatively, you can **test for specific *exception types***, using the **`-ExceptionType`** parameter:

```
{ 1 / 0 } | Should -Throw -ExceptionType System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException
```

Note that you **must pass the *full* type name**; omitting the `System.` component (which PowerShell often allows) is *not* recognized by `-ExceptionType`.

To identify the type of the exception associated with the most recent error, use `$Error[0].Exception.GetType().FullName`

---

**Complete example**:

Store the following in a `*.tests.ps1` file and invoke it either directly or via `Invoke-Pester`.
All of these tests should pass.

```
Describe "Error-handling tests" {

  BeforeAll {
    # Define an advanced function that generates a terminating error.
    function Get-FooTerminating {
      [CmdletBinding()]
      param()
      # When invoked by Pester, $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()
      # would have the same effect here, but note that $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError()
      # creates a *statement*-terminating error, whereas Throw creates a more
      # severe *script*-terminating (thread-terminating) error.
      Throw "me for a loop"
    }
    
    # Define an advanced function that generates a non-terminating error.
    function Get-FooNonTerminating {
      [CmdletBinding()]
      param()
      Write-Error "Something went mildly wrong."
    }

  }

  It "A terminating error throws." {
    { Get-FooTerminating } | Should -Throw
  }

  It "A non-terminating error doesn't throw." {
    # Note: Non-terminating errors are *passed through*, so
    #       we silence them with 2>$null here.
    { Get-FooNonTerminating 2>$null } | Should -Not -Throw
  }

  It "A non-terminating error promoted to a terminating one does throw." {
    { Get-FooNonTerminating -ErrorAction Stop } | Should -Throw
  }

  It "A fully qualified error ID can be tested for." {
    # Test for a (substring of) the error record's .FullyQualifiedErrorId 
    { NoSuchCommand } | Should -Throw -ErrorId CommandNotFound
  }

  It "A specific exception type can be tested for." {
    # Note the need to specify the type name *in full*, including the
    # 'System.' part
    { NoSuchCommand } | Should -Throw -ExceptionType System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the answer from mklement0 you need to wrap whatever you pipe to the assertion in a script block in order to use the `-Throw` check. This is the only assertion type where you need to do this.

Note you can also negate the check using `-Not`:

```
Describe 'Test' { 
    It 'Should Throw' { 
        { Throw } | Should -Not -Throw 
    }
}
```

Returns:

```
Describing Test
  [-] Should Throw 15ms
    Expected no exception to be thrown, but an exception "ScriptHalted" was thrown from line:3 char:11
        +         { Throw } | Should -Not -Throw
        +           ~~~~~.
    3:         { Throw } | Should -Not -Throw
```